# Ruby on rails: function to find value by key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I just encountered a problem with ruby syntax:

The enum example is:

```
class AaaBbb < ApplicationRecord

 enum number: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5 }
```

or

```
class AaaBbb < ApplicationRecord

 enum number: { "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 5 }
```

The function is:

```
  def find_value
    AaaBbb.numbers.each do |key, value|
        puts "#{key} = #{value}"
      if key == AaaBbb.numbers[:key] (WRONG CODE HERE, NEED TO FIX)
        return value
      else
        return 0
      end
    end
  end
```

So I am trying to write a function that if it finds the key, then return the value.

Comment: `enum number...` declares a column in the AaaBbb model called 'number' to be an `enum` column type. What are you expecting `AaaBbb.numbers` to be? There is no class method `numbers` that is related to the enum column.

Comment: @LesNightingill Rails auto generates the plural method when you declare an enum

Comment: @maxpleaner are you sure? I'm not seeing it in Rails 6.1.4.1, I do see a singular class method with the same name as the enum column. (it returns the hash of key/values for the column).

Comment: @maxpleaner you're right..., and I'm not seeing it in my app b/c the column name pluralized is the same as the singular! (it's 'via').

Answer (score 2):

You use `AaaBbb.numbers[:key]` instead of `AaaBbb.numbers[key]` .. that is, you're passing the symbol `:key` instead of the actual value `key`.

Also, looks like you have a second problem. Your loop will always end after running the first time. This is because `return` in Ruby isn't scoped to the `each`. It will return from the *method*, e.g. ending the loop immediately.

But really, I would just rewrite this method using simpler logic. I don't think you need a loop here at all.

```
def find_value(key)
  val = AaaBbb.numbers[key] # this will be nil if the key isn't found
  val || 0
end
```

Comment: Or `AaaBbb.numbers.fetch(key, 0)`

Comment: I am trying to use AaaBbb.numbers[key] before, but all product price in the front end shows 0.

Comment: Also since I need to use the the result to find_value to calculate.
eg: 
  `def calculator_example`
    `find_value * 2`
  `end`


If I add the 'key' param in the find_value(key), how can I change this the function for calculator_example

many thanks!!

Comment: Please see the updated post, thank you

Comment: Well, what is the key which you are trying to look up? You haven't shown that anywhere.